# Why isn't my image displaying using SDL2?

Tags: c, sdl-2

I just started coding a game using SDL2 in C, but I quickly ran into a problem : my images are not displayed on the window. I already made the following checks:

- the window and the renderer are successfully created
- my .bmp files are correctly loaded
- the SDL_RenderCopy() function is called, and returns no error
- the SDL_RenderPresent() function is called and returns no error
- I'm not trying to display my images on a 0x0px surface
- my image is a .bmp file

Here is some code, I hope this will help (I'm sorry it's quite disorganized):

Edit: I simplified the showed code

TrapAdventures.c (main file):

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "HobbesSDL.h"
#include "TrapInit.h"
#include "TrapKeyboard.h"
#define Ellipsis (return 0)
#define Pass ((void)0)
#define NullKeycode ((SDL_Keycode)0)


int main(void){
    HobbesBool TrapRunning = HOBBES_TRUE;
    
    HobbesWindow *TrapWindow;
    HobbesRenderer *TrapRenderer;
    if (TrapInitContext("Trap adventures", &TrapWindow, &TrapRenderer) != 0){
        TrapRunning = HOBBES_FALSE;
    }
    
    HobbesSprite *TrapPlayer;
    if (TrapInitSprite(&TrapPlayer, TrapRenderer) != 0)
        TrapRunning = HOBBES_FALSE;
    
    while (TrapRunning){
        if (TrapGetKeyState(TrapKeySpace))//Quit program if spacebar is pressed
            TrapRunning = HOBBES_FALSE;
        
        SDL_RenderClear(TrapRenderer);
        if (HobbesDisplaySprite(TrapPlayer) != 0){
            printf("Error while displaying player!\n");
            TrapRunning = HOBBES_FALSE;
        }
        SDL_RenderPresent(TrapRenderer);
        SDL_Delay(50);
    }
    
    HobbesDestroySprite(TrapPlayer);
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(TrapRenderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(TrapWindow);
    HobbesQuit();
    printf("End!\n");

    return 0;
}
```

The HobbesSprite type defined in HobbesSDL.h (my own (and small) library, using SDL2):

```
typedef struct HobbesSprite {
    SDL_Renderer *renderer;
    SDL_Surface *surface;
    SDL_Texture *texture;
    HobbesRect *rect;
    HobbesHitbox *hitbox;
    HobbesBool hidden;
} HobbesSprite;
```

Some of the functions in HobbesSDL.c that I use in this code:

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include "HobbesSDL.h"
#include <errno.h>

int HobbesInit(void){
    int ret = SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    if (ret != 0)
        fprintf(stderr, "Error while initializing SDL2: %s", SDL_GetError());
    return ret;
}

int HobbesDisplaySprite(HobbesSprite *sprite){
    if (SDL_RenderCopy(sprite->renderer, sprite->texture, NULL, (SDL_Rect *)sprite->rect) != 0 && !sprite->hidden){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error while displaying sprite: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        fclose(stderr);
        return -1;
    }
    
    return 0;
}

void HobbesUpdateWindow(HobbesRenderer *renderer){
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
}
```

TrapInit.c:

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include "HobbesSDL.h"
#include "TrapInit.h"

/*These first four functions will be used to initialize the rendering context*/

int TrapInitSDL(){
    return HobbesInit();
}

HobbesWindow *TrapInitWindow(const char name[]){
    SDL_Window *window = SDL_CreateWindow(name, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 0);
    if (window == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error while creating window: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
    }
    
    return window;
}

HobbesRenderer *TrapInitRenderer(HobbesWindow *window){
    SDL_Renderer *renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, 0);
    if (renderer == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error while creating renderer: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
    }
    
    return renderer;
}

int TrapInitContext(const char name[], HobbesWindow **wptr, HobbesRenderer **rptr){
//Initializes the rendering context using the above functions

    int InitSDLResult = TrapInitSDL();
    *wptr = TrapInitWindow(name);
    *rptr = TrapInitRenderer(*wptr);
    if (InitSDLResult != 0 || *wptr == NULL || *rptr == NULL)
        return 1;

    return 0;
}


/*The following function will be used to create every sprite needed in the game*/

int TrapInitSprite(HobbesSprite **Player, HobbesRenderer *renderer){

    *Player = HobbesCreateSprite(renderer, "Images/Player.bmp", 0, 724);
    
    if (*Player == NULL)
        return 1;

    return 0;
}
```

(I'm sorry that my code is so unclear, but I do my best :) )

My OS is MacOS Big Sur 11.6.4, my graphic card Intel Iris Pro Graphics 6200 1536 Mo, my processor is a 3,3 GHz Intel Core i7 four cores.

Finally, even thought I use the gcc command to compile, my compiler is clang (Apple made the choice to use clang by default, but the command is still gcc…).

If you need any other information, just ask in the comments and I'll answer you the best I can.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: `fclose(stderr);` is generally not a good idea.

Comment: It was suggested to me by another user of StackOverflow. The problem is that if I don’t close it, the message could be displayed only when the program ends. But thank you for your proposition!

Comment: `stderr` is not buffered. If you did happen to be successful closing it you would no longer be able to write to it. There's so much spam in the log you posted it's hard to follow the flow. My advice is to make a small simple example all in one c file that tries to display a single bitmap.

Comment: Just a quick look ... In your primary loop in `main`, you're doing: `HobbesDisplaySprite / SDL_RenderClear / SDL_RenderPresent`. But the clear call _destroys_ the data you've just created!? Would: `SDL_RenderClear / HobbesDisplaySprite / SDL_RenderPresent` be better?

Comment: Maybe someone will be able to spot the error, but normally we require minimal self-contained programs (i.e. single file, minimal layers of abstraction), see [mcve].

Comment: @Craig Estey You're right, that was an error. But after fixing it, it still doesn't work…

Comment: I wrote a little testing code that displays my sprite in the window. It works properly and it looks like the value of `errno` doesn't mean anything : `errno` is almost never 0 in my testing code, but still it works perfectly

Comment: *"It works properly"* So the problem is solved?

Comment: No, I meant that it worked if I used only SDL2. But as soon as I use HobbesSDL, this doesn't display anything

Answer (score 0):

I did a lot of tests, and finally found the problem.
The problem was that I tried to convert a `HobbesRect *` to a `SDL_Rect *`, but I did it wrong. If you look at the code of HobbesDisplaySprite, I do something like this:

```
SDL_RenderCopy(sprite->renderer, sprite->texture, NULL, (SDL_Rect *)sprite->rect) //(SDL_Rect *)sprite->rect is the problem
```

I solved my problem using a far more explicit conversion:

```
SDL_RenderCopy(sprite->renderer, sprite->texture, NULL, &((SDL_Rect){sprite->rect->x, sprite->rect->y, sprite->rect->w, sprite->rect->h}))
```

Thank you all for your interest in my problem! I'll try to put less code in my question next time ;) !